# Error message "This version of the entity data source wizard is only compatible with entity framework 5."when connect to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use visual studio community 2015 and when connect to MS Sql database using Entity Framework 6.0 as data source I got the error message shown in picture below:

[image]

Thanks a lot,
Harreni

Comment: [Try with this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609609/visual-studio-2013-and-entity-framework) I think it will work for you by downgrading to EF 5

Comment: Yes, I downgraded to 5 and it works. Thanks a lot Swarup

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if this is the latest patch level for Visual Studio 2015?

Also, if I am not mistaken, please install Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource and Microsoft.AspNet.DynamicData.EFProvider packages from NuGet (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/02/28/announcing-the-release-of-dynamic-data-provider-and-entitydatasource-control-for-entity-framework-6/).